# how to match the scale and position of background images

Tags: interface, image

I am having issues with two background images not being scaled to each other. One is set to front view with the dimensions of 310x506 pixels. The other is set to the right view with dimensions of 124x506 pixels.

Both Images have offset x of 0.00 and offset y of 5.00 in Background Settings.

I create a plane centered at location 0,0,0 and in both views the object is lined up but if I change the z to line up with the top of the image in the front view it doesn't line up with the top of the image in the right view.

What is causing this and how to I fix it?

Comment: Please add an image of your current setup to understand your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deal with background images by setting them to the same size before starting Blender in an external image processing package like Gimp. In your case, Ixd adjust the right view by enlarging the front view by padding the right view by adding 93 pixels on both sides of the image, so that the right view has the same dimensions as the front view, that is 310 x 506 pixels. This will make it easier to line up the images with the views.